# Can i use IBM Cognos Navigator and IBM Cognos Search on a web application

Tags: javascript, cognos, cognos-bi

I am currently working on a project that requires me to use existing IBM Cognos reports in a JavaScript web application. I am stuck on how to integrate all the functionalities provided by IBM Cognos. Is there any API that i can use for this and if so could you please point me in the right direction.

I am most particularly interested in being able to use the IBM Cognos Navigator and IBM Cognos Search in my application.

Please feel free to provide any alternatives that you may know of. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cognos 10.2.2 then you can accomplish this with the IBM Cognos Mashup service.
A good starting point for that is [Get started with the IBM Cognos Mashup Service](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1001cognosmashup/)
It is NOT easy or simple, so be warned. Good luck.